# How to create an raster map which shows number of occurences of vector layers

Tags: qgis, raster

I have a lot of vector layers which each contain a cloud mask. I would like to create one single raster layer, which shows the number of occurrences of clouds above every single cell.

How can do this?

I work with QGIS (version 3.22.5)

Ultimately, I would like to automate this process (using Python) in order to perform the analysis for thousands of layers.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest approach would be to rasterize all vector layers to the same template raster where areas with no cloud would be 0 and areas with clouds would be 1, and then just add all the rasters together.